# Understanding the subs argument in LogLocator

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to understand the `subs` argument in the `LogLocator` class, which determines where major / minor ticks should be located on a MatPlotLib graph.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(30)
y = np.power(x, 1.5)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

And this produces the following graph:

[image]

However, what I want to do is to have labels on the y-axis for all those ticks, rather than just at 10^0, 10^1, 10^2. I believe that the way to do this is to use a `LogLocator`, and so I have tried inserting the following into my code:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LogLocator(base=10, subs=np.arange(2, 10) * 0.1))
```

The idea here is that it would then show labels on 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 .... X 10^0, 10^1, 10^3 ...

However, instead, the graph appears to have removed all labels entirely:

[image]

So what should I be using in the `subs` argument to get my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line after `plt.plot()`. You will have a bit of space problem between the minor ticks due to the log spacing. But you can control that via the `fontsize` of the minor tick labels.

```
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.1f"))
```

**Output**

[image]